# How to save selected text from richTextBox to file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm selecting text in richTextBox1 and I can't save it to .txt file.
I was trying in many ways but only output I get was:

- all text from file
- output: true

Code that I'm using right now:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFiles = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFiles.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
        saveFiles.Filter = "txt Files | *.txt";

        if (saveFiles.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(saveFiles.FileName);
            foreach (String s in richTextBox1.Lines)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(s);
            }
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to save the *selected* text, but your code is trying to save *all* the text.  Try it this way:

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFiles.FileName, richTextBox1.SelectedRtf);
```

If you are interested in *only* the selected text part of the box, you can try something like this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(saveFiles.FileName,
             richTextBox1.SelectedText.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, the second options is the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method for saving the entire RichTextBox content as RTF

```cs
  richTextBox.SelectAll();
  using (var f=File.OpenWrite(filepath)) {
    richTextBox.Selection.Save(f, DataFormats.Rtf);
  }
```